# ntv2 datum transformations-problem on file output

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, datum

I am working with qgis 2.18.27
I have installed ntv2 datum transformations and it worked fine, but yesterday it didn't work and i am not finding the way to resolve the issue (explained below)

I am using the portugal ntv2 grids (direct and inverse vector transformation)

The plugin after processing ouputs a blank shapefile.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Because it worked once but not now, does the data you're using now have a different coordinate reference system than the data you used before?

Comment: no. Now I have uninstalled qgis and reinstalled, and the problem persists. I think is something related with the plugin file location but im not sure. It's something with this plugin i am sure, because i installed manually and its the only one thats failing... the standard ones are working fine

Comment: in the events log show me the following error "2019-01-20T21:45:12 0 GDAL execution console output
   ERROR 6: Failed to initialize PROJ pipeline from `+proj=tmerc +lat_0=39.66666666666666 +lon_0=1 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +nadgrids=C:/Users/Hugo Silva/.qgis2/python/plugins\\\\ntv2_transformations/grids/ptLX_e89.gsb +wktext +pm=lisbon +units=m +no_defs' to `+proj=tmerc +lat_0=39.66825833333333 +lon_0=-8.133108333333334 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs': failed to load datum shift file